Equation for Counting Unique RREF "Cases" for any (m x n) Matrix
Given a real matrix $A$ of size $(m \times n)$, I am seeking to determine the number of unique reduced row echelon form (RREF) "Cases" that exist for a given matrix size. Two RREF matrices are considered to be in the same 'Case' if they have the same structure, i.e., they have 1's, 0's, and non-zero elements (represented by variables) in the same positions.
For example, consider the $2 \times 2$ matrix. From our definition, we can see that there are FOUR unique RREF cases:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} - \text{Rank } 0$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & a\\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} - \text{Rank } 1$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} - \text{Rank } 1$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} - \text{Rank } 2$$
*Note that in case 2, $\begin{bmatrix}1 & a\\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $a$ represents any real number, including $0$. All matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1 & a\\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, regardless of the value of $a$, are considered to be in the same case.
I have done my best to find all the unique RREF cases for matrix sizes up to $3 \times 3$ (see attached image), but I am struggling to generalize this into an equation that works for any matrix size $m \times n$.
Unique RREF Cases to 3x3

Hi, please refrain from attaching images when they can be written using MathJax.

The number of distinct forms for the RREF of an $m\times n$ matrix is
$$
\sum_{r=0}^m\binom nr
$$
In particular, when $m\ge n$, the number of forms is $2^n$. For $m<n$, there is no way to write this quantity without a summation.
You can prove this by giving a bijection between RREF forms of $m\times n$ matrices with rank $r$, with paths in a $r\times (n-r)$ box, using the idea in this answer of mine. The number of such paths is well known to be $\binom nr$. Conclude by summing over all possible ranks.
